# Getting string value from url

Tags: javascript, html

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/activate_account.html#123,572ad7f557455";
var userid = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
var pass = url.substring(url.indexOf(",") + 1);

console.log("User id: " + userid + "Password: " + pass);
```

I would like to get string from the URL as value but when I try javascript code like above the value has been given is not what I want. The output that I get from code above is like this:

```
userid : 123,572ad7f557455 pass : 572ad7f557455
```

The problem is the userid. How can I display only 123 before the comma?

```
userid : 123
```

Comment: If you are really working in web development, i would suggest you stick to the "GET" , which is the query string method and supported by large variety of libraries.var url = "http://www.example.com/activate_account.html#123,572ad7f557455"; become var url = "http://www.example.com/activate_account.html?userid=123&pass=572ad7f557455";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set end index for `substring()` method by `url.indexOf(",")` like this:

```
var userid = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1, url.indexOf(","));
```

**N.B.** `split()` may help you if there is no `,` at password field.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/activate_account.html#123,572ad7f557455";    
var urlData = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
var userinfo = urlData.split(',');

console.log("User id: " + userinfo[0]);
console.log("Password: " + userinfo[1]);
```

It's work if your password in param don't have `,`.

If you password have `,`, use `slice` to make sure it work:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/activate_account.html#123,572ad7f557455";
var urlData = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
var userinfo = urlData.split(',');
var userId = userinfo[0];
var userinfo = urlData.split(',');
var userPassword = urlData.slice(userId.length + 1, urlData.length); // userId.length + 1 to remove comma

console.log("User id: " + userId);
console.log("Password: " + userPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/activate_account.html#123,572ad7f557455";
var params = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1).split[','];    
var userid = params[0];
var pass = params[1];

console.log("User id: " + userid + "Password: " + pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to send params through URL, you need to change it like http://www.example.com/activate_account.html?paramName=123 then you can get your data by param name. And also sending user name and password like this is not good at all, you need to put that in authorization header which will be encoded by base 64 for security purposes.